# JQuery space validation

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validation-engine, custom-validators

I am using Jquery custom validation for no space.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("noSpace", function(value, element) { 
      return value.indexOf(" ") < 0 ; 
});
```

And its working fine.
But it also fire validation when I used space between the word like 
"Test Example".

Example 1 :: "      "   //Validation (Its fine.)
Example 2 :: "Test Example"   //Validation (I dont want validation in it.)

Basically I don't want a space in a starting but requrired space between the word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use trim(). I'm not pretty sure about the validator, but you can try this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("noSpace", function(value, element) { 
      return (value.trim() == value) && (value.indexOf(" ") > 0);
});
```

Edit: the correct answer:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("noSpace", function(value, element) { 
      return (value.trim() == value) && (value.indexOf(" ") < 0); 
})
```

Comment: Yes I will but after I will not get validation of blank space in my textbox.

Comment: So you need spaces in the middle of the text?

Comment: Yes.
Example 1 :: "      "   //Validation Occurs (Its fine.)
Example 2 :: "Test Example"   //Validation (I dont want validation in it.)

Comment: You can combine your solution with mine. Take a look at my edited answer

Comment: I also tried this but now example 1 is working and example 2 fired validation.

Comment: as far as I understand, what you need is: No space at the begin and the end and There must be space(s) in the middle. Is it right?

Comment: Yes.
I exactly want this.

Comment: I edited my answer. Try it. If it still doesnt work, I think you can try changing the conditions (|| and &&, != and ==, etc...) in the formula to get the right solution.

Comment: jQuery.validator.addMethod("noSpace", function(value, element) { 
      return (value.trim() == value) && (value.indexOf(" ") < 0);
})

I did one change in your answer and its working now.

Comment: Please change your answer so other will also use this.